# Put the start and the end name of a point object into the layer of the line object that connects them?

Tags: qgis, point, attribute-table, line

I am new to QGIS. I am given two layers with point objects. In their attribute table each of this objects has a code (`name`) given previously to it by someone else. Then I import the lines from AutoCAD that connect those points. For those lines I have created 2 fields in their attribute table that say `'Start point'` and `'End point'`. In the field `'Start point'` in the line object table, I should include the code(`name`) from the first point object, and in the field `'End point'` I should include the name of the end point object.

Since there are many lines like this, and each of them connects 2 point objects, is there an option that can do that automatically without me having to type each code(name) differently?

Comment: How do you decide that a point is start or end point?

Comment: those lines are cables that connect one pole to each house address. The code for the pole is always a start point and the code for the home address is always an end point.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have one point layer for the poles and
one for the houses, you should be able to get this done
using the *NNJoin* plugin (If your QGIS version is
recent you can also use the *Join attributes by nearest*
algorithm).

1) Use *NNJoinJoin*, with your line layer as *Input vector
layer*, the pole layer as *Join vector layer* and `pole_`
as *Join prefix*.
The result is a line layer where for each line, the
fields of the nearest pole in the pole layer have been
added (the names of these fields will all have `pole_` as a
prefix), together with the distance from the line to that
pole.
If you would like to use the `distance` field from this
join, you will have to rename it, so that it is not
overwritten in the second step.

2) Use *NNJoinJoin*, with the output (line)
layer from your first join as *Input vector layer*, the house
layer as *Join vector layer* and `house_` as *Join prefix*.
The result is a new line layer where for each line, the
field of the nearest house in the house layer has been
added (the names of these fields will all have `house_` as a
prefix), together with the distance from the line to that
house.

3) Open the attribute table of the resulting line layer
and, using the field calculator, set the value of the
*Start point* field to the value in the `pole_name` field.
Set the value of the *End point* field to the value in
the `house_name` field in the same way.

4) (optional) Remove the fields that were added from the
pole and house layers from the new line layer.

If there are houses closer to the line than the destination
house, they will be chosen, because the whole line is
considered when searching for the nearest nearest neighbour.
To avoid this, you will first have to
extract the start and end points of the line and use the
resulting point layers for the joining, and afterward join
the attribute tables from the results of these joins back
into the line layer (remember to include IDs for the lines
in the start and end point layers, so that you can join
them back after the nearest neighbour join).